# Get key events in CheckedListBox control when a listbox item is selected

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a CheckedListBox as the base for a custom DataGridView cell classes edit mode.  I want to close the edit when the user presses the escape key.  If the user doesn't have anything selected overriding OnKeyDown works perfectly.  The problem is that if they do OnKeyDown (and OnKeyPressed) aren't fired by the CheckedListBox; instead the row item deselects itself and eats the event.  This means that if the user makes a selection by clicking on any item in the list it takes two presses of escape to close the edit.  One to unselect the row they clicked on, and a second to cancel edit mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the escape key I had to change the behavior of IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey (equivalent of IsInputKey on normal controls) to pass escape to my OnKeyDown event.

```
/// <summary>
/// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey method.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="key"></param>
/// <param name="dataGridViewWantsInputKey"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
{
    // Let the custom edit control handle the keys listed.
    switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Escape:
            return true;
        default:
            return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to override the IsInputKey on your custom DataGridView itself and return false if it's [Esc], thus the grid ignores Esc.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.isinputkey.aspx

You could maybe enhave this behavior by only ignoring the inputKey if there's nothing in 'edit mode' or similar.

Comment: I tried overriding this on my CellEditControl, but changing it to return true instead of false when the escape key is pressed still doesn't let it reach the CellEditControl's KeyDownEvent.

Comment: Explicitly calling OnKeyDown() from within IsInputKey() managed to achieve what I wanted; but ugh is it a nasty kludge.

Comment: It turns out the problem was with `IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey` I didn't need to touch IsInputKey at all because this method lets you do the same thing and was firing afterwards and trashing the change I tried to make in isInputKey

Comment: Ah, good point.  Yeah, custom DataGridView controls are always a little tricky to work with their events. Also, suggest you post your own answer to this question, then select it as the answer.  Then anyone asking a similar question can come to your solution.